# Swashbuckle - Web API Controllers inheriting from BaseController are not shown

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an OWIN, self-hosted Web API project and I want to add Swagger documentation and Swagger UI to it.

I have included the Swashbuckle.Core package and I have configured it manually, in `Startup.cs`.

```
configuration.EnableSwagger(s =>
{
    s.SingleApiVersion(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Replace('.', ' '), "MyApi").;
    s.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\MyApi.XML");
    s.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
})
.EnableSwaggerUi(s =>
{
    // By default, swagger-ui will validate specs against swagger.io's online validator and display the result
    // in a badge at the bottom of the page. Use these options to set a different validator URL or to disable the
    // feature entirely.
    //c.SetValidatorUrl("http://localhost/validator");
    s.DisableValidator();
});
```

Now, I have a base controller and two additional controllers that inherit from the base. Unfortunately I don't see the controllers' names and actions in swagger page.

Here is my base controller:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        // Initialization...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction()
    {
        // Code here...
    }
}
```

Controler1:

```
public class My1Controller : BaseController
{
    public MyController1(...): base(...)
    {
        // Initialization...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Model1 model)
    {
        // Code here...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Model2 model)
    {
        // Code here...
    }
}
```

Controller2:

```
public class My2Controller : BaseController
{
    public My2Controller(...): base(...)
    {
        // Initialization...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Model1 model)
    {
        // Code here...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Model2 model)
    {
        // Code here...
    }
}
```

I can't see the `My1Controller` nor the `My2Controller` in swagger index page. I have tried the `ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` attribute on `My1Controller` and `My2Controller` but nothing happened.

Is it because controllers actions share common names (multiple `Post` actions with different parameter types)? I am not using RPC-style URLs as it seems from the example above, rather RESTful URLs, following the 5 Levels of Media Types (5LMT) proposal.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your issue hat you don't see methods from the base Controller or that you don't see methods from base & child Controller?

Comment: @bsoulier correct, I don't see both in swagger documentation page

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Web API works with [naming conventions](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/02/but-i-dont-want-to-call-web-api-controllers-controller/), which means that your controllers are not parsed because they don't have their names ending with `Controller`.

This means `MyController1` becomes `My1Controller`.

So as an example, changing `MyController1` to the following will work:

```
public class My1Controller : BaseController
{
    public MyController1(...): base(...)
    {
        // Initialization...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Model1 model)
    {
        // Code here...
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Model2 model)
    {
        // Code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just for demonstration, controllers follow the naming conventions. Updating question as it seems misleading.

Comment: No pb, provide more real sample next time

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to name the routes differently so that they don't have naming conflicts for shared methods.

add the attribute

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)]
```

to your basecontroller
and the attributes

```
[Route("/My1Service")]
[ServiceName("My1Service")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
```

and the

```
[HttpPost(nameof(StoreCardPaymentMethod))]
```

to each method or something like that

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are not able to see them is because swashbuckle only reads ApiCOntrollers, any other than that e.g OdataController, must be added by the developer with he help of a custom document filter. here is n example
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/README.md